# Should we declare the condition we are using before the for loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

For example, if I am using the length of an array to determine how many times the code in the for loop runs, should I initialise the count of the array on top of the for loop so that the program does not keep calculating the length of the string?

Some simple code that prints each element in the array:

Without initialising the size of the array

```
int myArray[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

for (int iPos = 0; iPos < size(myArray); ++iPos)
    cout << myArray[iPos];
```

initialising the size of the array before the for loop

```
int myArray[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

int sizeOfArray = size(myArray);
for (int iPos = 0; iPos < sizeOfArray; ++iPos)
    cout << myArray[iPos];
```

Answer (score 5):

`for (int iPos = 0; iPos < size(myArray); ++iPos)` will calculate the size of `myArray` on each iteration.
This *may* be important if the size of `myArray` can change in the body of the loop. So be careful.

If the size of `myArray` cannot change in the loop, then extracting the calculation to before the loop as `const int sizeOfArray = size(myArray);` *may* gain you a *tiny* bit of performance if the compiler does not realize this itself and hoists the calculation out of the loop on its own.

A simpler way to do it would be to just use a range-for loop, since those are defined to only calculate the size once:

```
for (const auto& element : myArray)
    cout << element;
```

and then you also don't have to worry about having the `sizeOfArray` variable exist in the scope outside the loop.

Comment: Indeed; it always seemed pointless to even _potentially, maybe_ recalculate the range on every iteration, optimisations notwithstanding, but some people disliked the "scope leak" inherent in hoisting out part of the conditional; range-based for fixes that!

Comment: "*use a range-for loop, since those are defined to only calculate the size once*" - such a loop does not calculate a count at all, since it is internally implemented using iterators, not indexes and counts. The starting and ending iterators are retrieved once before the loop is then run.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Which, if we aren't being pedantic, equates to calculating the size just *once*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl except that there is no size calculated at all in a ranged for loop

Comment: @RemyLebeau Now you are being pedantic 

Answer (score 2):

[sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator is a compile time one, so there are no problems since you are using static arrays.

For a dynamic array, calling `std::vector::size()` could in theory be executed multiple times, but a good optimizing compiler will cache it as long as you don't modify the vector inside a loop.

Even if it doesn't, [size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) takes little time to execute (constant complexity).